# Using ActiveRecord models in a gem - how to handle database config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several active record models in a rails app and I would like to extract these models into a gem so that I can easily use them in several web apps. The process seems pretty straight forward, except for passing along the configuration for the models. Do I:

1. Add the configuration yaml file to the gem, thus assuring the databases will always be the same across all apps - seems rigid, esp for testing and dev, though the databases for production will always be consistent.
2. Use the ActiveRecord hooks to look for a database.yml file in the config directory with the database defined? If so, which hooks should I use?
3. This is a stupid idea. If you have a better way to handle this, I'm all ears. I'd prefer not to copy and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the host rails app's database config. Your plugin or gem should contain just the database migrations, and a rake task to run them from the host rails app (e.g. `myplugin:db:migrate`)

If your models need some other configuration file, you should create a rake task (e.g. `myplugin:install`) to copy it to your host app's config directory. (This task can call the db:migrate task automatically as well.)

Comment: yah, good call, like the cucumber gem adding the cucumber env to the db config file. I was going down this path but this helped me clarify the though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to embed the database.yml file inside the gem? Each rails application should use it's own database.yml

I would put all the models into a plugin and include that in each rails application that needs the models.

Comment: curious, why a plugin over a gem? 

One reason I considered embedding the database.yml file was because this is internal and the db is not changing, we could manage it all from one location - just update the gem. Also, what if I am using the models and the database connection outside a rails app, eg a command line app that is load testing the database.